# Show the value of an integral using integration by parts.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $$\! \int t^2e^{-t^3} \ \mathrm{d}t$$ using integration by parts.

I know how to use substitution to evaluate this integral, when I use integration by parts letting $u = e^{-t^3}, \mathrm{d}v = t^2\ \mathrm{d}t$ I get $$\frac13t^3e^{-t^3}+\int\! t^5e^{-t^3}\ \mathrm{d}t$$ but this leads me to nowhere. Thanks

Comment: Integration by parts is not necessary to evaluate this integral. But the usual  strategy is to choose a different $u$, $\mathsf dv$ if the first choice didn't work. Here is a resource that may prove useful in determining how to choose $u$ and $\mathsf dv$ https://mathnow.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/liate-ilate-and-detail/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
\int_{t} t^{2}e^{-t^{3}} = \int_{t} De^{-t^{3}}(\frac{-1}{3}) = \frac{-1}{3}e^{-t^{3}} + C
$$
by the chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus.

I am not sure why you are required to do it by integration by parts. But, in this case, there is no need to use it...